# How to Find the Branching Factor of a Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, search-tree

A particular search tree has 6 nodes at level 3. At the next level, there are 24 nodes. What is the branching factor at level 3?

The answer is 4, but can someone tell me why, I thought that it was 2.

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_factor

Answer (score 20):

From Wikipedia:

> In computing, tree data structures, and game theory, the branching factor is the number of children at each node, the outdegree. If this value is not uniform, an average branching factor can be calculated.

You have 6 nodes at level 3, 24 nodes at level 4, so the average number of children per node at level 3 is `24/6=4`.

Answer (score 3):

On different types of trees the branching factor can be either a `static` value throughout the tree, which only happens in `perfect binary trees` or an `average` `branching factor` which is most time the case for trees.

The branching factor is one characteristic of a node next to `depth` and gives a clue how complex a tree gets. For example, for the `GO Game` on a 19x19 board, the branching factor on the first level is `361`, after 4 more moves at depth `4` you end up having `10 billion` nodes. (possible moves)

Source: An Introduction To Artificial Intelligence, Janet Finlay

Answer (score 0):

You could also just draw a search tree. Start with level 3. 6 nodes have 24 successors. It means that each of the 6 nodes has 24/6= 4 children. You can check this: 6 parent nodes * 4 children = 24 nodes on level 4. The branching factor at level 3 is thus 4.