# How to calculate the average branching factor on a given tree

Tags: math, data-science, computer-science, game-ai, search-tree

Can anyone explain to me, what the value of the average branching factor is if we exclude leaf nodes when computing b?

Example:

[image: Tree]

I don't know how to calculate this in the right way :/

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each non-terminal node and average the number of branches it has. In your example, the average should be between 1 and 2.

Related:
[How to Find the Branching Factor of a Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789400/how-to-find-the-branching-factor-of-a-tree)